# "João jogou bola na estrada" é ambíguo?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, ambiguidades

Essa frase significa que João estava na estrada enquanto jogava bola ou que a bola caiu na estrada?

Me parece que nesse caso João estava na estrada enquanto jogava bola. Porém se substituo "bola" por "água" ficaria "João jogou água na estrada", daí me parece que a água foi jogada na estrada. Se esse for o caso, O que a bola tem que a água não tem?

Como escrever esse tipo de frase de modo que não fique ambíguo?

Comment: Em Portugal não escrevemos assim, incluimos o artigo indefinido; por isso não temos ambiguidade: "João jogou à bola na estrada", "João jogou a bola na estrada". :) Tivémos sorte.

Comment: No Brasil também é assim.  Quando alguém diz "jogar bola", isso significa algum jogo, geralmente futebol.  Quando atira-se o objeto, o artigo definido é usado e todos nós sabemos a diferença entre "jogar bola" e "jogar a bola".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No meu entender a interpretação preferível para "jogar bola" é a de jogar futebol (ou um jogo de bola, mas para futebol é mais comum):

- Ele gosta de jogar bola.

Qualquer um interpretaria a frase como jogar futebol.

"Jogar a bola" seria o ato de atirar a bola.

Se tirarmos o contexto cultural, a frase fica ambígua sim.

Para evitar:

- João jogou futebol na estrada.
- João lançou a bola na estrada.

Uma vez que "jogar bola" é uma expressão coloquial.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, essa frase é ambígua. A forma mais fácil é estabelecer um contexto anteriormente, como dizer que o João já estava na rua quando tal evento aconteceu implica que João joga bola estando na rua, por exemplo. É uma questão de contexto para a quebra da ambigüidade.

Comment: Para a resposta ficar _mesmo_ boa, sugiro um exemplo explícito de como escrever a frase. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Em pt-BR**, na região que habito, **não há nenhuma ambiguidade** porque são expressões idiomáticas, com significado bem conhecido por todos.

> Ele gosta de jogar bola na estrada. (jogar bola = jogar futebol)
>
> Ele engoliu mosca. (ele ficou de bobeira, perdeu a oportunidade por estar distraído, bobeou)
>
> Eu não engulo sapo. (não deixo de revidar quando me ofendem, xingam, ou dizem algo muito desagradável)
>
> Ele jogou verde. (ele disse uma mentira a respeito de algum fato do qual suspeitava, pra ver se conseguia que a outra pessoa acabasse revelando alguma informação)

**Mas, se usarmos o artigo, definido ou indefinido, o significado muda completamente.**

> Ele gosta de jogar a bola na estrada (ele gosta de arremessar a bola na estrada)
>
> Ele engoliu a mosca sem querer (engolir, em seu sentido literal)
>
> Eu vi quando o crocodilo engoliu o sapo. (idem)
>
> Ele jogou o verde. (não jogou nem o objeto azul e nem o vermelho)

Portanto, não há nenhuma ambiguidade.